# Javascript: using ternary operator to return default value if a function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

given this function

```js
function isTastyCheese(cheeseName: string) {
    const TastyCheeses = ['camembert', 'maroilles']
    if (TastyCheeses.includes(cheeseName)) {
        return 'yes so tasty'
    }
    return undefined
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```js
const answerCamembert = isTastyCheese('camembert') ? the_returned_value : 'no taste like sh*t' 
const answerCantal = isTastyCheese('cantal') ? the_returned_value : 'no taste like sh*t'

console.log(answerCamembert)
>>> 'yes so tasty'
console.log(answerCantal)
>>> 'no taste like sh*t'
```

How do i use *ternary operator* to do this concisely?

*PS: Obsviously the function presented here is very wrong but changing it shouldn't be part of the solution*

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. What's do you mean by _concisely_?

Comment: The logical OR operator is your friend here: `const answerCantal = isTastyCheese('cantal') ||  'no taste like sh*t'`. Or, if you support newer platforms, the nullish coalescing operator is probably even better: `const answerCantal = isTastyCheese('cantal') ?? 'no taste like sh*t'`

Comment: Or the newer, slightly more appropriate [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: I agree with @Ben Aston, unless using a ternary operator is a mandatory requirement.

Comment: If this is a thought experiment, and you absolutely must use the ternary conditional operator, then the following would work (but is horrendous): `var answerCamembert = (answerCamembert = isTastyCheese('camembert')) ? answerCamembert : 'no taste like sh*t' `. Note the use of `var` to skirt around limitations of the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz) associated with `let`, and assignment constraints associated with `const`.